# JavaScript - Add Objects to Object and Remove via Key/Value Pair

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, javascript-objects

I'm trying to finish a JS script where the objective is to add & remove first names & last names from an object. It's going to be transferred via AJAX to a PHP script which will then manipulate the JSON, so keeping that in mind... What am I supposed to use to make an object which:

1. Has pairs of first & last names
2. Can have its pairs of first & last names removed by stating a key (ie, "First") and a value

I know it's simple but none of the solutions I've read have worked yet! Sorry for the dumb question...

**EDIT:** I have no way of identifying each full name - all I have to go by is the first name & last name. In fact I have an object with a bunch of objects within it, which looks like this in Chrome's JS console:

```
[Object, Object, Object, Object]
0: Object
    first: "Stewie"
    last: "Griffin"
1: Object
    first: "Peter"
    last: "Griffin"
2: Object
    first: "Stan"
    last: "Smith"
3: Object
```

The code that makes this is:

```
window.selectednames.push({
first: $(this).find('.firstname').text(), 
last: $(this).find('.lastname').text()
});
```

OR for testing purposes, here it is with the data:

```
window.selectednames.push({
    first: 'Stweie', 
    last: 'Griffin'
    });
window.selectednames.push({
    first: 'Peter', 
    last: 'Griffin'
    });
window.selectednames.push({
    first: 'Stan', 
    last: 'Smith'
    });
```

This seems ideal! I just don't know how to delete from this collection of objects when all I know is the first & last name (in other words, when I don't know the number/count/index).

Comment: None of the good stuff is relevant.. I guess I can try to build up some more context...

Comment: ^. Probably have read this: [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Please see my edit above...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use javascript objects:

For example you can have an array of names as follows

```
var names = new Array()
var name1 = new Object();
name1.first = "Brad";
name1.last = "Pitt";
names.push(name1);
```

And when it comes time to convert the array to json, just use

```
var jsonStr = JSON.stringify(a);
```

In response to your post edit, you could always have the following function

```
function removeNameFromList(nameList, firstName, lastName) {
    for(var i = nameList.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
         if(nameList[i].first == firstName && nameList[i].last == lastName) {
              nameList.splice(i, 1);
         }
    }
}
```

Note that this function will remove all occurrences of the first and last name combo.

Comment: You mean `JSON.stringify`.

Comment: I sure did.  Thanks Felix

Comment: Please see my edit above...

Comment: Thanks, it's so close, but I get this error now: `Cannot read property 'first' of undefined` on the `for` line. It can get through one of the objects - when I run `console.log(nameList[i]);` between the `for` and the `if`, it outputs an object and it even gets deleted if it's the matching object and it happened to be run through first, but the second object to go through fails every time with this error...

Comment: If I add `if("first" in nameList[i]){` immediately after the `for` line and add the appropriate `}`, I get `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'first' in undefined`, as if there is no `list[i]`! It's not like the whole object is being destroyed - I can still console.log it and it looks like it did beforehand.

Comment: It should have been i-- instead of i++.  My fault for not having tested before posting.  Hope this helps- mark as correct answer if it does